# React native firebase phone number authentication opens safari before sending sms. Bad UX

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication, react-native-firebase

the phone number authentication working fine, however when I'm calling

```
firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
```

It opens safari browser and does few redirects displaying "Verifying you are not a robot" and then close itself.
Is it normal behavior when using "react-native-firebase" and is there any option to hide this weird in terms of UX behavior?

Note: Testing it on ios, didn't try on android yet.

P.S.

I've used firebase phone number auth before in web and it has the ReCaptcha. Using it in the native apps I would expect more silent behavior.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Ok found the solution.
First, you need to enable receiving silent notifications.
In your xcode "capabilities" enable push notification and background modes.
Follow the firebase doc below:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth#start-receiving-silent-notifications